# SMTP : error relaying

Tags: c#, email, smtp, windows-server-2008

i am creating an email client that sends e-mail address from server ip instead of SMTP , i wrote that code:

```
SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("50.23.128.66");
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("from@yahoo.com", "tome@yahoo.com", "subject", "body");
server.Send(msg);
```

but when i run it , i get that error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Relaying Denied.
>       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressColl
>       ection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)

*** By the way i am using Windows Server 2008 ***
and i configured the smtp server to localhost and port 25 , but i don`t know what is that relying error .

Comment: When you send a `someone@foo.com` email through an `bar.com` SMTP server, you are using the `bar.com` server as a mail relay.  If the `bar.com` server is not configured to relay mail, it will reject SMTP attempts that aren't part of its own domain, or users on it.  In other words this is not a programming error, but a server error, and you should check with the server configuration.  Perhaps better suited to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaying is the method the SMTP server uses to authenticate that it should route the email from a particular sender.  An "open relay" means that there is no authentication and the SMTP server will send email sent from anyone. This is not a good practice and there are probably some mechanisms on this particular SMTP server to authenticates, such as a user name and password or even the IP address of the sender.  Check with the administrator of the SMTP server to see what is required.  I would think at a minimum you would need to set the user name and password, which you did not do in your code example.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using you localhost to rely email, you should be using 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead of that ip address you posted in your code.

Comment: yes , but i have 3 ips on that server and i want to switch ips when sending emails , so that i dont be a spammer

Comment: Who said that by switching ips you won't be flagged as a spammer? It's more complicated than that.